# Image rotator plugin

Tags: plugins

I have tried two Rotator plugins so far. Nivo-slider and EasyRotator. Nivo-slider was great, but i could only have an image caption, and i need both image caption and image title. Also, i couldn't get the "bullets" for indicating the current slide to work. So i Googled and found the "EasyRotator"-plugin. Great, except it rescales the images, even if i upload in the correct resolution, the generated HTML is all inline styling so it's kind of hard for me to style it as i want from css. Now im wondering, is there any plugin that does the following?

1. Image Title
2. Image Caption
3. Bullets to indicate current slide

Any tip is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Slide can handle that. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-slide/

And the plugin site: http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-content-slide-plugin/

It's a champ and handles all three of your conditions. 'Bullets' are square, you can mod that though. Have fun!